# Why doesn't Laravel's required_without_all validation recognize my parameters?

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5.4

I want to validate that an input is required **only** if the other two inputs are empty. So I'm using the **required_without_all** validation rule for this.

According to the Laravel 5.4 documentation for [Required Without All](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-required-without-all):

> The field under validation must be present and not empty only when all of the other specified fields are not present.

However I think that I don't know what **Present** means according to Laravel because I thought it meant the inputs must be filled.

When I run the test leaving the username empty, it always returns the following error regardless of the firstname and lastname inputs being filled or empty:

> The username field is required when none of firstname / lastname are present.

Here's my validation on the controller:

```
public function test()
{
    $this->validate(request(), [
        'username' => 'required_without_all: firstname, lastname',
    ]);

    return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: my bad, does *When I run the test leaving the username empty* means that the other two field not empty?

Comment: ah i see! try to add to your validator rule that `'firstname'` and `'lastname'` as `required`. fyi, [this is how the validation executed](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php#L1169) then trace to [allFailingRequired](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php#L1199) method. and all make sense. good grief Laravel is open source.

Comment: @BagusTesa I added the required rule for `'firstname'` and `'lastname'` and it shows the same error when leaving the `'username'` empty. But now it shows me the respective require errores for those fields if I don't fill them.

Comment: @BagusTesa I see those methods, but I still don't know what "Present" means and why it's always failing. It seems **fistname** and **lastname** are never Present regardless if the fields are filled or empty... However adding the rules `'firstname' => 'present'` and `'lastname' => 'present'` never actually return any errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's something wrong with the code. There shouldn't be any **spaces** on the firstname and lastname parameters. The code should be:

```
'username' => 'required_without_all:firstname,lastname',
```

Instead of:

```
'username' => 'required_without_all: firstname, lastname',
```

So required_without_all works fine now. Sorry guys, I updated the question so it fits the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is the method definition:

````
``
    /**
     * Validate that an attribute exists when all other attributes do not.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed   $value
     * @param  mixed   $parameters
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function validateRequiredWithoutAll($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
        if ($this->allFailingRequired($parameters)) {
            return $this->validateRequired($attribute, $value);
        }

        return true;
    }
```
````

So as you see, validation passes when all other attributes are not given.

Comment: I see. And since those attributes are text inputs, not being given would mean not entering anything on the fields? because even if they are filled I still get the same message as a result:

Comment: I'm not sure now, there could be a problem anywhere, I don't your data specifically. But, if you get stuck, you can use custom validation after hook: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#after-validation-hook